# Handle email validation event in html5 and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, events

I have below email input in my page

```
<input type="email" value="" id="emailId" class="validate[required] text-input">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="runProgress();" title="Submit" id="submitId">

function runProgress() {
    //After successful validation (how to check this)?

    //code for changing visibility flag of progress popup
    $("#alertcontainer").css("display", "block");
}
```

My implementation is like when I submit my page, I show processing popup which greys out my screen using jquery.

For now it is showing validation error but my jquery function grays out my screen. So I want to check if validation error has come then I will not grey out my screen.

I am using sample code. I want to apply this to other validations also like number and all.

**So can I get any flag/function which will show that there is not validation message in my form?**

Thanks.

Comment: try gray out your screen after validation success .. or provide the code for beter help..

Comment: Yes, I want to check for validation success, is there any function for that?

Comment: how is your validation.. provide me a code..

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample..

```
 var validator = $('#form').validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        email: ''
      },
      success: function() {
        console.log('success'); // do something here.. here is the success
      },
      highlight: function() {
        console.log('highlight');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. But I am using sample code. I want to apply this to other validations also like number and all. So for all that I will have to write like this. So instead of writing for each, can I get any flag which will show that there is not validation message in my form?

Answer (score 0):

as your code describes..

```
 function runProgress() {
        if(!isValidEmailAddress($("#sc_email").val())) (
            $("#alertcontainer").css("display", "block");
          return false;         
       }
        else if($("#customername").val()=='' OR $("#customername").val()==' ') { 
           $("#alertcontainer").css("display", "block");
           return false;         
      }
        else{
          return true; //do something
      }
   }

function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

Comment: `check fist field`, what is the code for that condition?